# Error: Malformed entry 1 while trying to get ROS Kinetic. How do I fix this?

Tags: software-sources, ros

I'm trying to install ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu Xenial and this is 
the error:

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros.latest.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

What do i add to this line on the file?

The only entry from `sources.list.d/ros.latest.list`:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenialmain
```

Comment: You're showing us the first entry from `/etc/source.list` but the error is about the first entry in `/etc/source.list.d/ros.latest.list`. Please [edit] your question and show us that file instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenialmain` there needs to be a space between "xenial" and "main"